# React Redux <Connector>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

How to make this part of code working with new versions of redux? 
This is working with reudx < 1.0 version https://github.com/reactjs/redux/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc
But now `Connector` from `react-redux` - `undefined`
Is it possible to make this work?

***Part of code***

```
import { Connector } from 'redux/react;

<Connector select={state => ({
                            center: state.map.get('mapInfo').get('center'),
                            zoom: state.map.get('mapInfo').get('zoom'),
                            markers: state.map.get('dataFiltered'),
                            visibleRowFirst: state.map.get('tableRowsInfo').get('visibleRowFirst'),
                            visibleRowLast: state.map.get('tableRowsInfo').get('visibleRowLast'),
                            maxVisibleRows: state.map.get('tableRowsInfo').get('maxVisibleRows'),
                            hoveredRowIndex: state.map.get('tableRowsInfo').get('hoveredRowIndex'),
                            openBallonIndex: state.map.get('openBalloonIndex')
                        })}>
                            {({dispatch, ...mapProps}) => (
                                <Map {...mapProps}
                                     {...bindActionCreators(mapActions, dispatch)}
                                />
                            )}
                        </Connector>
```

Comment: Why such an old version? Did you mean `Provider` not `Connector`? Also, IIRC it should be `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)`.

Comment: @AndrewLi , no i mean `Connector` -> here is example 
https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react-examples/blob/master/web/flux/components/examples/x_main/main_map_page.jsx

Comment: I really suggest upgrading Redux, React Redux, and React for future support. Not many people can help with React Redux <v1.0...

Comment: yeah 
I want to do but don't know how to replace this part with new version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class Map extends React.Component
{
//Your Map component
}

const mapStateToProps = (state = {}) => {
    return {
        center: state.map.get('mapInfo').get('center'),
                            zoom: state.map.get('mapInfo').get('zoom'),
                            markers: state.map.get('dataFiltered'),
                            visibleRowFirst: state.map.get('tableRowsInfo').get('visibleRowFirst'),
                            visibleRowLast: state.map.get('tableRowsInfo').get('visibleRowLast'),
                            maxVisibleRows: state.map.get('tableRowsInfo').get('maxVisibleRows'),
                            hoveredRowIndex: state.map.get('tableRowsInfo').get('hoveredRowIndex'),
                            openBallonIndex: state.map.get('openBalloonIndex')
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(mapActions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Map);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the package is changed to react-redux. Try importing that.

Comment: According to these docs Connector has been moved, https://github.com/reactjs/redux/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc, and there's also a missing apostrophe on the import of `redux/react`